# Game with server and multiple client, make sure only one game object is created

Tags: java, networking, graphics, graphics2d

I'm trying to write a poker server and client program, I create the game in the server class and my client class takes the output and displays them. However, when ever i do this, there seem to be two game objects created, the first player gets the input that is consistent with the object that is shown in the console, the second player always displays cards that are not shown in the sysout method, and I can not seem to find where I created the second game object.

server class:

```
 import java.io.BufferedReader;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashSet;

public class PokerServer {

/**
 * The port that the server listens on.
 */
private static final int PORT = 9050;
// keeps track of all the names
private static ArrayList<String> names = new ArrayList<String>();
// broadcast messages
private static ArrayList<PrintWriter> writers = new ArrayList<PrintWriter>();
private boolean bothPlayersConnected = false;

/**
 * The appplication main method, which just listens on a port and spawns
 * handler threads.
 */
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    System.out.println("The poker server is running.");
    ServerSocket listener = new ServerSocket(PORT);
    try {
        while (true) {
            new GameThread(listener.accept()).start();
        }
    } finally {
        listener.close();
    }
}

private static class GameThread extends Thread {
    private String name;
    private Socket socket;
    private BufferedReader in;
    private PrintWriter out;
    private Game game;

    public GameThread(Socket socket) {
        this.socket = socket;
    }

    /**
     * Services this thread's client by repeatedly requesting a screen name
     * until a unique one has been submitted, then acknowledges the name and
     * registers the output stream for the client in a global set, then
     * repeatedly gets inputs and broadcasts them.
     */
    public void run() {
        try {
            System.out.println("get to this part");
            // Create character streams for the socket.
            in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
            out = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);


            // get the name of the player
            out.println("SUBMITNAME");
            name = in.readLine();
            names.add(name);

            while(names.size()<2){
                out.println("MESSAGE waiting for opponent to connect");
            }

            // Now that a successful name has been chosen, add the
            // socket's print writer to the set of all writers so
            // this client can receive broadcast messages.
            // out.println("NAMEACCEPTED");
            // writers.add(out);

                game = new Game(names.get(0), names.get(1), 1000);

                game.dealToPlayers();

                out.println(names.get(0) + game.getPlayer1().getHand()[0].transferStr());
                out.println(names.get(0) + game.getPlayer1().getHand()[1].transferStr());
                out.println(names.get(1) + game.getPlayer2().getHand()[0].transferStr());
                out.println(names.get(1) + game.getPlayer2().getHand()[1].transferStr());

                // Accept messages from this client and broadcast them.
                // Ignore other clients that cannot be broadcasted to.
                while (true) {
                    String input = in.readLine();
                    if (input == null) {
                        return;
                    } else if (input.startsWith(names.get(0))) {

                    }
                    for (PrintWriter writer : writers) {
                        writer.println("MESSAGE " + name + ": " + input);
                    }
                }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        } finally {
            // This client is going down! Remove its name and its print
            // writer from the sets, and close its socket.
            if (name != null) {
                names.remove(name);
            }
            if (out != null) {
                writers.remove(out);
            }
            try {
                socket.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
            }
        }

    }

}

}
```

Client class

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;

import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class PokerClient {

    BufferedReader in;
    PrintWriter out;
    String playerName = "Poker";
    JFrame frame = new JFrame(playerName);

    JPanel playerHandPanel, controlPanel, bottomPanel, topPanel, messageBoard;
    JButton check, fold;
    JTextField textField = new JTextField(10);
    JLabel firstLine = new JLabel("");

    String serverAddress = "localhost";

    Card playerHand1, playerHand2;


    public PokerClient() {

        // Layout GUI
        frame.setSize(1100, 700);
        frame.setResizable(true);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);


        playerHandPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(1, 0));
        playerHandPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(600, 300)); 
        playerHandPanel.setVisible(true);

        topPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(1, 0));
        topPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(900, 300)); 
        topPanel.setVisible(true);

        messageBoard = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0, 1));
        messageBoard.add(firstLine);

        controlPanel = new JPanel();
        controlPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(600, 40));
        controlPanel.setVisible(true);

        topPanel.add(messageBoard);

        check = new JButton("Check");
        check.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                out.println(playerName+"CHECK");
            }
        });

        fold = new JButton("fold");
        fold.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                out.println(playerName+"FOLD");
            }
        });

        textField.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                if(isInt(textField.getText())){
                    out.println(textField.getText());
                    textField.setText("");
                } else{
                    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Not a number");
                    frame.setSize(600, 70);
                    frame.setLocation(400, 250);
                    frame.setResizable(false);
                    JLabel label = new JLabel("You must enter a number in order to raise");
                    frame.add(label);
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                    frame.toFront();
                    frame.repaint();
                    textField.setText("");
                }
            }
        });

        controlPanel.add(check);
        controlPanel.add(fold);
        controlPanel.add(new JLabel(" Raise:"));
        controlPanel.add(textField);

        bottomPanel = new JPanel();
        bottomPanel.add(controlPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        bottomPanel.add(playerHandPanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);



        frame.add(topPanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        frame.add(bottomPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        //frame.add(firstLine, "SOUTH");
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }


    private static boolean isInt(String s)
    {
     try
      { int i = Integer.parseInt(s); return true; }

     catch(NumberFormatException er)
      { return false; }
    }

    /**
     * Prompt for and return the desired screen name.
     */
    private String getName() {

        return JOptionPane.showInputDialog(
            frame,
            "Choose a screen name:",
            "Screen name selection",
            JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
    }

    private Card constructCard(String line){
         int seperator = line.indexOf('/');
         int cardNum = Integer.parseInt(line.substring(0, seperator));
         Card card;
         if(line.substring(seperator+1).startsWith("S")){
           card = new Card(cardNum, Suit.SPADE);
         } else if(line.substring(seperator+1).startsWith("C")){
           card = new Card(cardNum, Suit.CLUB);
         } else if(line.substring(seperator+1).startsWith("D")){
           card = new Card(cardNum, Suit.DIAMOND);
         } else{
           card = new Card(cardNum, Suit.HEART);
         }
         System.out.println(card.toString());
         return card;
    }

    /**
     * Connects to the server then enters the processing loop.
     */
    private void run() throws IOException {

        Socket socket = new Socket(serverAddress, 9050);
        in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
            socket.getInputStream()));
        out = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);



        // Process all messages from server, according to the protocol.
        while (true) {
            String line = in.readLine();
            System.out.println(line);
            if (line.startsWith("SUBMITNAME")) {
                String name = getName();
                playerName = name;
                out.println(name);
                frame.setTitle(playerName);

            } else if (line.startsWith(playerName)) {
                playerHandPanel.add(new CardComponent(constructCard(line.substring(playerName.length()))));
                playerHandPanel.revalidate();
                playerHandPanel.repaint();
            } else if(line.startsWith("CARD")){
                topPanel.add(new CardComponent(constructCard(line.substring(4))));
                topPanel.revalidate();
                topPanel.repaint();
            } else if(line.startsWith("MESSAGE")){
                firstLine.setText(line.substring(7));
            }
        }
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        PokerClient client = new PokerClient();
        client.frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        client.frame.setVisible(true);
        client.run();
    }
}
```

Comment: Why not create Thread Safe Singleton class of Game?

Comment: @PritamBanerjee Can you explain? I'm new to networking.

Comment: You can look here: http://www.javaworld.com/article/2073352/core-java/simply-singleton.html

Comment: Look at the thread safe Singleton

Comment: I may be going off on a rant here but why do you find it necessary to use private static and I do hope you have complete control of it

Comment: @PritamBanerjee thank you that actually helped. I was able to solve my problem. I initialized the game in the run method and that creates multiple instances.

Comment: Can you please post your solution? That will be helpful for the future readers.

Comment: All I did is initialize the game outside of the run method.